# jquery ajax post onclick - php session variable

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, session, post

On my homepage I'm using the maximage fullscreen image plugin. When someone clicks on a 
specific link (product page), I must find out what the current image in the slideshow is
and set it as the background-image in the product index page.

I'm making an ajax call the moment someone clicks the '/producten' link on the homepage and store it as a session variable.

The problem is, it's not making an ajax call, I can't see the POST request in my apache logfile, only the GET request for the '/producten' page. Is it going to fast? Can't I do a POST request just before I make the GET request? I can't pinpoint it. Here's my code:

homepage index:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($)
{
    $("a[href='/producten']").click(function() {
        var best;
        var maxz;
        $('.mc-image').each(function() {
            var z = parseInt($(this).css('z-index'), 10);
            if (!best || maxz<z) {
                best = this;        
                maxz = z;
            }
        });
        var bg_image = $(best).css('background-image');
        bg_image     = bg_image.replace('url(','').replace(')','');

        $.post('/producten', {bg_image:bg_image});
    });
});
```

bg_image is set correctly, I tested it with a console.log(), and I get output.

/producten index:

```
<?php
    session_start();

    $_SESSION['bg_image'] = $_POST['bg_image'];
?>
```

Comment: What says your *Network* tab of Dev Tools? Thus, you may try to put a `preventDefault()` inside your `click` event.

Comment: Try to analyze the network tab in something like firebug

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the event.preventDefault() and the network tab. When inserting the event.preventDefault(), it does make the POST request. I made a check.php file, printing out the $_SESSION variable and it's set. But it does not work when I remove the event.preventDefault(), it's empty. Seems like it's going to fast, and I'm developing it on my own machine, even. What could it be?

Comment: I would simply add the bg_image to the url, set the session variable if bg_image is set and redirect to plain /producten

Comment: Setting this value in the session has the potential of messing things up quite beautifully when the user has more than one tab with your site open …

Comment: I tried setting the async option to false in the ajax call, but that did not help either. Hmmmm.

Comment: @CBroe That's alright in this case. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In javascript:

```
/* $.post('/producten', {bg_image:bg_image}); */
this.href = this.href + '?bg_image=' + escape(bg_image)
```

In php:

```
if(isset($_GET['bg_image'])) {
  $_SESSION['bg_image'] = $_GET['bg_image'];
  header('Location: /producten');
  exit;
}
```